# UNIX, find string in all files in sub directory with line numbers and filenames

Tags: unix, recursion, grep, find

I'm trying to do a recursive text string search in UNIX and have the results show both the filename and line number on which the text appears within the file. Based on some other answers here I have the following code, but it only shows line numbers and not filenames:

```
find /my/directory -type f -exec grep -ni "text to search" {} \;
```

It would also be great to have this command ignore everything except for .LOG files. For what it's worth, grep -r is not supported on my system. Thanks!

Comment: that's because by default grep won't add file name for single input.. try `+` instead of `\;` if your version of find supports it.. or use `-H` with grep if your version of grep supports it

Comment: What does `man grep` tell you about printing the file name?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
find /my/directory -type f -name "*.LOG" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Hni "text to find"
```

Answer (score 0):

When your `find`and `grep` don't support advances options, try adding `/dev/null`

```
find /my/directory -type f -exec grep -ni "text to search" {} /dev/null \;
```